# FCM Data messages: need to send JSON array in place of String value

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

As per firebace doc, we can send FCM data messages in below format:

```
{
"message":{
"token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMEFQ3P1...",
"data":{
  "Nick" : "Mario",
  "body" : "great match!",
  "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
}
}
}
```

But, I am required to send data as JSON Array like below:

```
{
"message":{
"token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
"data":{
       "geofence":[{
                     "Nick" : "Mario",
                     "body" : "great match!",
                    "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
                    },
                    {
                    "Nick" : "Mario",
                    "body" : "great match!",
                    "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
                    }]
}
}
}
```

I am getting below error if I try to send JSON Array in request body for sending messages:

Unable to send message to Firebase:

```
  {  "error": 
   {    "code": 400,    
"message": "Invalid value at 'message.data[0].value' (Map), Cannot have repeated items ('geofence') within a map.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"\" at 'message.data[0].value': Proto fields must have a name.",    
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",    
"details": [      {        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",        "fieldViolations": [          {            "field": "message.data[0].value",            "description": "Invalid value at 'message.data[0].value' (Map), Cannot have repeated items ('geofence') within a map."          },          {            "field": "message.data[0].value",            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"\" at 'message.data[0].value': Proto fields must have a name."          }        ]      }    ]  
}}
```

Android code is expecting data in JSON Array format not in String. I am stucked here badly.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that error matches the payload you're sending?  The error mentions repeated "geofence" items, but your payload doesn't mention that at all.

Comment: @DougStevenson geofence is CUSTOM_KEY nothing else. I've corrected JSON key.

Comment: @SSingh I got solution : Hope it will help you some how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55428420/1318946

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The values in the data payload must be strings.  You can't have arrays or objects.  Your geofence is an array.

You can see from the Android API for [RemoteMessage.getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getData()) that the return type is `Map<String, String>`, which implies that you can only have string values.  You can see also in the [protocol docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#resource-message) that the data payload is string keys mapped to string values.  So, you're going to have to figure out a way to flatten your data to strings.

Comment: You are right. Now I have sent JSONArray as String and its successfully sent data to android device.

Comment: @SSingh how did you solved it? here I have [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417458/parse-nested-json-array-from-notification-data-using-gson-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using JavaScript, you can use `JSON.stringify(object)` and, at the receiver, end you can use `JSON.parse(stringObject)`.