# Parse Nested JSON Array from Notification Data using Gson in Android

Tags: android, json, gson, firebase-notifications

I am getting data in JSON format from FCM notification. It has different format based on notification types as below:

**Format 1: accept_request:**

```
{
   "alert": "Accept Request By driver",
   "title": "Accept Request By driver",
   "booking_id": "247",
   "notification_type": "accept_request"
}
```

**Format 2: end_request:**

```
{
    "alert": "End trip By driver",
    "title": "End trip By driver",
    "booking_id": "247",
    "notification_type": "end_request",
    "servicesList": [
        {
            "service_id": "1",
            "service_name": "Services1",
            "status": "true",
            "sub_category": [
                {
                    "sub_cat_id": "1",
                    "sub_cat_name": "Doctors on call",
                    "service_cost": "15.00",
                    "service_cat_id": "1",
                    "cost": 0
                }
            ],
            "is_multiple_choose": "0",
            "total_cost": 15
        }
}
```

I have create `CommonNotificationBean.java` as POJO class. I have successfully parsed data for `accept_request`.

Its working because all key has String values and `remoteMessage.getData()` also returning `Map<String, String>` type values.

**Code:**

```
    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("notification_type"));
        Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(object.toString()));
        reader.setLenient(true);
        CommonNotificationBean bean = gson.fromJson(reader, CommonNotificationBean.class);

        sendNotification(bean);
    }
```

### PROBLEM:

**Now I am stuck with problem while parsing `end_request` data because it has Nested JSON Array.**

## Read it carefully:

**What can I do for dynamic data instead of `Map<String, String>`** because it will not convert data into `Map<String, String>` type as it has some `List` type values.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Then try this method : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22855546/4385913

Comment: Just put comment if question have any mistake before giving down vote.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this problem correctly. You have `remoteMessage.getData()` which returns `Map<String, String>`. After that you convert this map to `JSON` using `JSONObject` which comes from `org.json`. Finally, you deserialise this `JSON` to `CommonNotificationBean` using `Gson`. `Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();` line gives some problems - but what is the problem? Do you have exception? What is a type of `remoteMessage`? How do you deserialised this incoming `JSON` to `remoteMessage.getData()`? To handle all values you need to define map as `Map<String, Object>`

Comment: Simply, `remoteMessage.getData()` returning `Map<String, String>` type values but I am getting sometime `Map<String, List<String>>` type values. How can I get it and convert to my POJO class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And finally I got solution by adding some drops of concepts. :)

I got many problems to converting in JSON with proper format like:

- Unterminated object at character
- MalformedJsonException

and Finally following code get worked for me.

```
  if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "remoteMessage.getData() : " + remoteMessage.getData());

        // Map<String, String> stringStringMap = remoteMessage.getData();

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());

        Log.d(TAG, "new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData()) : " + object.toString());

        String finalJSON = object.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", "").replace("\"[", "[").replace("]\"", "]");

        Log.d(TAG, "Replace all back slash and invalid double quotes : " + finalJSON);

        CommonNotificationBean bean = new Gson().fromJson(finalJSON, CommonNotificationBean.class);

        sendNotification(bean);
    }
```

Logcat:

**remoteMessage.getData():** Getting data without double quotes.

```
remoteMessage.getData() : {content-available=1, notification_type=end_request, booking_id=247, priority=high, base_price=35, totalMinutePrice=1.5, alert=End trip By driver, sound=default, title=End trip By driver, total_amount=397, address_from=A/ 4 forum bungalow Nr. Hicort, Sola, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380015, India, service_cost=360, servicesList=[{"total_cost":15,"sub_category":[{"cost":0,"sub_cat_name":"Doctors on call","sub_cat_id":"1","service_cost":"15.00","service_cat_id":"1"}],"service_name":"Services1","service_id":"1","is_multiple_choose":"0","status":"true"},{"total_cost":95,"sub_category":[{"cost":0,"sub_cat_name":"Hand","sub_cat_id":"3","service_cost":"20.00","service_cat_id":"2"},{"cost":0,"sub_cat_name":"Body","sub_cat_id":"4","service_cost":"75.00","service_cat_id":"2"}],"service_name":"Dressing","service_id":"2","is_multiple_choose":"1","status":"true"},{"total_cost":0,"sub_category":[{"cost":0,"sub_cat_name":"No","sub_cat_id":"7","service_cost":"0.00","service_cat_id":"3"}],"service_name":"Do you need oxygen?","service_id":"3","is_multiple_choose":"0","status":"true"},{"total_cost":30,"sub_category":[{"cost":0,"sub_cat_name":"Level 3","sub_cat_id":"10","service_cost":"30.00","service_cat_id":"4"}],"service_name":"Lift\/Stairs Accessibility","service_id":"4","is_multiple_choose":"0","status":"true"},{"total_cost":220,"sub_category":[{"cost":0,"sub_cat_name":"Ventilator","sub_cat_id":"12","service_cost":"100.00","service_cat_id":"5"},{"cost":0,"sub_cat_name":"Intracenous (IV) drip","sub_cat_id":"13","service_cost":"120.00","service_cat_id":"5"}],"service_name":"Other Medical","service_id":"5","is_multiple_choose":"1","status":"true"},{}], tripdatetime=2019-03-27 10:57:51, address_to=19/20, Chanakyapuri, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 382481, India, notification_date_time=28-03-2019 17:24:09}
```

**new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData()) :** Converted to JSONObject but **getting unwanted back slash and double quotes**

```
new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData()) : {"content-available":"1","notification_type":"end_request","booking_id":"247","priority":"high","base_price":"35","totalMinutePrice":"1.5","alert":"End trip By driver","sound":"default","title":"End trip By driver","total_amount":"397","address_from":"A\/ 4 forum bungalow Nr. Hicort, Sola, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380015, India","service_cost":"360","servicesList":"[{\"total_cost\":15,\"sub_category\":[{\"cost\":0,\"sub_cat_name\":\"Doctors on call\",\"sub_cat_id\":\"1\",\"service_cost\":\"15.00\",\"service_cat_id\":\"1\"}],\"service_name\":\"Services1\",\"service_id\":\"1\",\"is_multiple_choose\":\"0\",\"status\":\"true\"},{\"total_cost\":95,\"sub_category\":[{\"cost\":0,\"sub_cat_name\":\"Hand\",\"sub_cat_id\":\"3\",\"service_cost\":\"20.00\",\"service_cat_id\":\"2\"},{\"cost\":0,\"sub_cat_name\":\"Body\",\"sub_cat_id\":\"4\",\"service_cost\":\"75.00\",\"service_cat_id\":\"2\"}],\"service_name\":\"Dressing\",\"service_id\":\"2\",\"is_multiple_choose\":\"1\",\"status\":\"true\"},{\"total_cost\":0,\"sub_category\":[{\"cost\":0,\"sub_cat_name\":\"No\",\"sub_cat_id\":\"7\",\"service_cost\":\"0.00\",\"service_cat_id\":\"3\"}],\"service_name\":\"Do you need oxygen?\",\"service_id\":\"3\",\"is_multiple_choose\":\"0\",\"status\":\"true\"},{\"total_cost\":30,\"sub_category\":[{\"cost\":0,\"sub_cat_name\":\"Level 3\",\"sub_cat_id\":\"10\",\"service_cost\":\"30.00\",\"service_cat_id\":\"4\"}],\"service_name\":\"Lift\\\/Stairs Accessibility\",\"service_id\":\"4\",\"is_multiple_choose\":\"0\",\"status\":\"true\"},{\"total_cost\":220,\"sub_category\":[{\"cost\":0,\"sub_cat_name\":\"Ventilator\",\"sub_cat_id\":\"12\",\"service_cost\":\"100.00\",\"service_cat_id\":\"5\"},{\"cost\":0,\"sub_cat_name\":\"Intracenous (IV) drip\",\"sub_cat_id\":\"13\",\"service_cost\":\"120.00\",\"service_cat_id\":\"5\"}],\"service_name\":\"Other Medical\",\"service_id\":\"5\",\"is_multiple_choose\":\"1\",\"status\":\"true\"},{}]","tripdatetime":"2019-03-27 10:57:51","address_to":"19\/20, Chanakyapuri, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 382481, India","notification_date_time":"28-03-2019 17:24:09"}
```

**Final JSON :**

```
Replace all back slash and invalid double quotes : {"content-available":"1","notification_type":"end_request","booking_id":"247","priority":"high","base_price":"35","totalMinutePrice":"1.5","alert":"End trip By driver","sound":"default","title":"End trip By driver","total_amount":"397","address_from":"A/ 4 forum bungalow Nr. Hicort, Sola, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380015, India","service_cost":"360","servicesList":[{"total_cost":15,"sub_category":[{"cost":0,"sub_cat_name":"Doctors on call","sub_cat_id":"1","service_cost":"15.00","service_cat_id":"1"}],"service_name":"Services1","service_id":"1","is_multiple_choose":"0","status":"true"},{"total_cost":95,"sub_category":[{"cost":0,"sub_cat_name":"Hand","sub_cat_id":"3","service_cost":"20.00","service_cat_id":"2"},{"cost":0,"sub_cat_name":"Body","sub_cat_id":"4","service_cost":"75.00","service_cat_id":"2"}],"service_name":"Dressing","service_id":"2","is_multiple_choose":"1","status":"true"},{"total_cost":0,"sub_category":[{"cost":0,"sub_cat_name":"No","sub_cat_id":"7","service_cost":"0.00","service_cat_id":"3"}],"service_name":"Do you need oxygen?","service_id":"3","is_multiple_choose":"0","status":"true"},{"total_cost":30,"sub_category":[{"cost":0,"sub_cat_name":"Level 3","sub_cat_id":"10","service_cost":"30.00","service_cat_id":"4"}],"service_name":"Lift/Stairs Accessibility","service_id":"4","is_multiple_choose":"0","status":"true"},{"total_cost":220,"sub_category":[{"cost":0,"sub_cat_name":"Ventilator","sub_cat_id":"12","service_cost":"100.00","service_cat_id":"5"},{"cost":0,"sub_cat_name":"Intracenous (IV) drip","sub_cat_id":"13","service_cost":"120.00","service_cat_id":"5"}],"service_name":"Other Medical","service_id":"5","is_multiple_choose":"1","status":"true"},{}],"tripdatetime":"2019-03-27 10:57:51","address_to":"19/20, Chanakyapuri, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 382481, India","notification_date_time":"28-03-2019 17:24:09"}
```

### Full code : [MyFirebaseMessagingService.java](https://gist.github.com/pratikbutani/5bb53db6b421af25541721229b9a8e74)

Hope it will be help to others.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, you should just have an abstract Notification object with the attributes `alert`, `title` and `notification_type`. And then, have specific implementations based on your possible types, so far:

- `AcceptRequestNotification extends Notification` with just an int `booking_id` (this is the one you already have, the one you called CommonNotificationBean)
- `EndRequestNotification extends Notification` which contains for example, an ArrayList called `servicesList`, this ArrayList should be of type `Service` and then, service would have the attributes: `service_id`, `service_name`, `status`, `sub_category` which is again another ArrayList of a custom type.

And then you just change your code to be:

```
// Check if message contains a data payload.
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("notification_type"));
    Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();

    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(object.toString()));
    reader.setLenient(true);

    Class typeOf;

    switch(remoteMessage.getData().get("notification_type")) {
        case "accept_request":
            typeOf = AcceptRequestNotification.class;
        break;
        case "end_request":
            typeOf = EndRequestNotification.class;
        break;
    }

    //you can cast this object later on (to the corresponding custom subclass of Notification), based on the notif.getNotificationType() value.
    Notification notif = gson.fromJson(reader, typeOf);

    sendNotification(notif);
}
```

Comment: The problem I am getting on this line : `remoteMessage.getData();` because it will not convert data into `Map<String, String>` type as it has some `List` type values.

Comment: If you debug the value of `remoteMessage.getData()` does the map contains a key for `servicesList`? if so, what is the value of it? if not, is it giving you any exception?

Comment: I got answer as I posted. Thank you for your time.